# What is the origin and purpose of the variable $data in KnockoutJS?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

In the [KnockoutJS tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail) I stumbled upon the following code example that contains an unexplainable variable `$data`.

The View (html):

```html
<!-- Folders -->
<ul class="folders" data-bind="template: { name: 'folderTemplate', foreach: folders }"></ul>
<script type="text/html" id="folderTemplate">
    <li data-bind="css: { selected: $data == mailViewModel.selectedFolder() },
                   click: function() { mailViewModel.selectFolder($data) }">
        ${$data}
    </li>    
</script>
```

The View Model (JavaScript):

```
var viewModel = {
    // Data
    folders: ['Inbox', 'Archive', 'Sent', 'Spam'],
    selectedFolder: ko.observable('Inbox'),

    // Behaviours
    selectFolder: function (folder) {
        this.selectedFolder(folder);
    }    
};

window.mailViewModel = viewModel;
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

The tutorial does not contain any explanation what that dollar sign is used for and where this `$data` comes from. The variable `$data` is nowhere defined and when I rename all three instances of `$data` to `$foobar`, the example does not work anymore.

What kind of magic is going on here?

Comment: Great question. I was struggling with this.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `$data` variable is a built-in variable used to refer to the current object being bound. In the example this is the one of the elements in the `viewModel.folders` array.

Comment: Thanks for your brief explanation. So the `$data` variable only exists when a `foreach` is used?

Comment: You can also supply its value by using the data parameter in the template declaration. Also, if neither the data or foreach parameter is present it defaults to the entire view model for the template

Comment: Are there any other built-in variables?

Comment: They really should've explained that

Answer (score 65):

$data is part of [Knockout's Binding Contexts](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html).

Here are all the built-in variables:

- $parent
- $parents
- $root
- $component
- $data
- $index (only available within foreach bindings)
- $parentContext
- $rawData
- $componentTemplateNodes

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't find it in the navigation on the site.

Answer (score 0):

i made it work

```
.selected {
    color:red;
}

<ul class="folders" data-bind="template: { name: 'folderTemplate', foreach: folders }"></ul>
<script type="text/html" id="folderTemplate">
    <li data-bind="css: { selected: $data == mailViewModel.selectedFolder() },text:$data,
                   click: function() { mailViewModel.selectFolder($data) }">
    </li>    
</script>

var viewModel = {
    // Data
    folders: ['Inbox', 'Archive', 'Sent', 'Spam'],
    selectedFolder: ko.observable('Inbox'),

    // Behaviours
    selectFolder: function (folder) {
        this.selectedFolder(folder);
    }    
};

window.mailViewModel = viewModel;
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

please take a look at
 http://jsfiddle.net/bowen31337/48RDd/

Comment: Making it work was not the problem. A solution is even available on the tutorial pages.