# knockout datacontext

Tags: knockout.js

I'm playing with knockoutjs and bindable grid(KoGrid). Js contextMenu is attached to each row. When I right click on a row I want to get data behind this row(datacontext). 
How I can do this with knockoutjs? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for $data, that's what represents the actual data element when doing foreach/template bindings etc.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7839243

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<table data-bind="event:{contextmenu: myFunctionName}, 
template:{ name: function()   {return selectedView(); }, foreach: articles }">

</table>
```

learn rest about defining and using "template"  in the following link

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Ujr4z/

i hope it may help