# How do I get the value of a control inside of a knockoutjs foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, foreach

I have a knockout foreach section and I am trying to get the values of the generated controls inside of a function bound to a click event for each section. For each section that is generated, when I click on the button I want to know what it's comment is.

//HTML

```
<div data-bind="foreach: areas">
<button data-bind="click: $parent.saveComment()" />
   <input type="text" data-bind="text: comment" />
</div>
```

//KnockoutJS function

```
saveComment: function(){
  console.log([value of the comment textbox]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically for an `<input>` you'll want to use the `value` binding. You can pass `$data` but it is not a requirement as that value will be passed automatically for you.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: areas">
  <button data-bind="click: $parent.saveComment">Save</button>
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: comment"></input>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Do not include any `()` on the `saveComment` binding and declare the function with a parameter in your model. The function will receive the value that represents the equivalent of `$data`.

```
saveComment: function (data) {
    console.log(data.comment());
}
```

Or if you prefer, you can simply use `this` inside of `saveComment` to refer to the "current" context.

```
saveComment: function () {
    console.log(this.comment());
}
```

Check out [my example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/kZyY4/) that contains both usages.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: areas">
<button data-bind="click: $parent.saveComment($data)" />
   <input type="text" data-bind="text: comment" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
saveComment: function(area){
  console.log(rea);
}
```

See:
[What is the origin and purpose of the variable $data in KnockoutJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838853/what-is-the-origin-and-purpose-of-the-variable-data-in-knockoutjs)